# Copy Paste data from columns of dynamic length

Tags: vba, excel

In an Excel file, I have 2 tabs: Input and Output.

In the tab Input, I have in column A, a list of codes like: code001, and it goes indefinitely, since I am adding more and more.

In column B I have a list of keywords like: blue dress, red pencil, white scarf, ... again I don't have the number of keywords since I am adding more and more.

On columns C and D, I have the same structure as A and B.
(The file structure cannot be changed!)

I want to put on the tab Output, on Column A, the codes (column A and column C from tab Input) and on column B, the keywords (column B and column D from the tab Input).

How can I go through all the columns and the rows, with a while cycle/function?

Comment: you can do this with worksheet formulas surely rather than writing VBA?

Comment: An easy way to identify the VBA code for something you know how to do in the user interface, is to record a macro of performing the function, and then inspecting the macro created. This is a very useful way to explore VBA, as well of learning new VBA functionality from the Excel object model.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should do this with worksheet formulas.
In column A on Sheet **Output** put this formula:

`=Input!A:A&Input!C:C`

in column B on sheet **Output** put this formula:

`=Input!B:B&Input!D:D`

If the issue is that you don't know anything about Excel VBA, then the below sites should help you:

- Here is a tutorial site that will help you: [Excel VBA Tutorial](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-VBA-Tutorial.html)
- to learn about the Excel Object Model in VBA see

  - [MSDN Library: Super Easy Guide to the Excel Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa203714%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
- to learn about working with cells and ranges in Excel VBA see

  - [MSDN Library: Working with cells & ranges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221536%28v=office.11%29.aspx)
  - [Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa272254(v=office.11).aspx)
- to learn abouut UserForms and Controls in Excel VBA see

  - [MSDN Library: UserForms in Excel VBA](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829070)
  - [Chandoo.org: User Forms & Controls in VBA](http://chandoo.org/wp/excel-vba/user-forms/)
  - [Excel VBA Easy - Excel VBA UserForm](http://www.excel-vba-easy.com/vba-userform-excel-vba.html)

Here are a few other websites for your reading:

- Excel MVP Site: [Contextures Excel](http://www.contextures.com/tiptech.html)
- Excel VBA Site: [Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/Topic.aspx)
- Excel MVP Site: [Ron De Bruin](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section9.htm)
- Mr Spreadsheet (John Walkenbach): [Spreadsheet Page](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tips)
- Mr Excel: [Mr Excel Site](http://www.mrexcel.com/)
- Charley Kydd Excel MVP: [Excel User dot Com](http://exceluser.com/explore/index.htm)
- McGimpsey & Associates Excel MVP Site[J.E. McGimpsey's XL Pages](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/index.html)

Best of luck

Philip

Comment: Thank you once again! It cannot be done with Excel formulas, it has to be with a macro.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late answer, but try this out. It's probably more complex than need be but there are a ton of ways you can do this.

```
Public Sub stuff2()
    Dim rangeA, rangeB, ranceC, rangeD As Range
    Dim numA, numB, numC, numD As Integer

    With Sheets("Input")
        numA = Worksheetfunction.CountA(.Range("A:A"))
        numB = Worksheetfunction.CountA(.Range("B:B"))
        numC = Worksheetfunction.CountA(.Range("C:C"))
        numD = Worksheetfunction.CountA(.Range("D:D"))
        Set rangeA = .Range("A1:A" & numA)
        Set rangeB = .Range("B1:B" & numB)
        Set rangeC = .Range("C1:C" & numC)
        Set rangeD = .Range("D1:D" & numD)
    End With

    With Sheets("Output")
        rangeA.Copy .Range("A1")
        rangeB.Copy .Range("B1")
        rangeC.Copy .Range("A" & numA + 1)
        rangeD.Copy .Range("AB" & numB + 1)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly I am  5 year late to offer a solution.... here's my approach to address it

```
Sub consol
 Dim maxi as long, restrtrow as long, i as long  
 For i = 1 to 4
   If i = 1 or i = 3 then
       Maxi= sheets ("input").cells (1000000,i).end (xlup).row
       Restrtrow = sheets ("output").cells (1000000,1).end (xlup).row+1
       Sheets ("input").select
       Range (Cells (2 ,i),cells ( maxi,i)).copy
       Sheets ("output").select
       Cells(Restrtrow,1).SELECT
       Selection.pastespecial paste:= xlpastevalues
     Elseif i =2 or i=4 then
         Sheets ("input").select
         Range (cells (2,i),cells (maxi,i)).select
         Selection.copy
         Sheets ("output").select
         Cells (2,restrtrow).select
         Selection.pastespecial paste:= xlpastevalues
     End if   

   next
 end sub
```